# Why does hard drive fail?

Tags: hard-drive, mount, raspberry-pi

For quite a while now I have a Seagate hard drive attached to a raspberry pi. The drive has external power. Every now and then the led on the drive would start flashing and the mount is gone from the system.

When  I unplug the drive and plug it back in it often recovers but not always. Recently it is becoming more and more often that the drive stops working. With the last crash I took following out of dmesg:

```
   49.105683] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion Desk   0739 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[   49.113781] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Spinning up disk...
[   49.150658] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[   54.610106] ......ready
[   59.661098] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 732566645 4096-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.73 TiB)
[   59.662073] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[   59.662117] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 2b 00 10 08
[   59.663050] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, supports DPO and FUA
[   59.689282]  sda: sda1
[   59.700659] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[   62.499883] EXT4-fs (sda1): recovery complete
[   62.510210] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[ 1481.946661] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link down
[ 6149.568206] usb 1-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 4
[ 6149.575001] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0
[ 6149.985052] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 6149.985394] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x01 driverbyte=0x00
[ 6150.181909] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 365985792, lost sync page write
[ 6150.181955] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for sda1-8.
[ 6150.181968] Aborting journal on device sda1-8.
[ 6150.181991] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 365985792, lost sync page write
[ 6150.182008] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for sda1-8.
```

Any ideas in what could be causing this?

Comment: About a thousand different reasons....

Answer (score 1):

It's either the interface on the pi, the enclosure interface/controller, or the drive itself.

1 - Try connecting to something else and see if you have the same issues.

2 - Remove the drive and mount in a PC--I would start by looking at the SMART table and running diags.